# How to run script before java application start directly from docker entrypoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]`

This is my current definition in my `Dockerfile`

Question: is it possible to simply execute another `.sh` script before that, without having to write an additional `entrypoint.sh` script?

Pseudocode:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["init.sh", "&&", "java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Instead of: `ENTRYPOINT[ "wrapper.sh" ]`

Comment: A Docker container runs a single process then exits.  You can have that process be whatever you want it to be, including a shell script that does multiple things.  I'd recommend the entrypoint wrapper script as a more flexible approach than what you have here; also be aware of the different between the shell and exec forms of `ENTRYPOINT` (what you have here will run `init.sh` as the only thing in the container and exit, passing the string `&&` as its first parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to run a script first is to use the shell version of the ENTRYPOINT directive rather than the exec version that you use (read https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint for more info).

Running a shell lets you run multiple commands by separating them with `&&`. So you can do

```
ENTRYPOINT init.sh && java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

If the process to start the container becomes more complex, you should create an entrypoint wrapper script like David suggests.